# Career 2.0: Is this number a Grand total, or just a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, stack-exchange-button

I've been granted 5 invitations on my Careers 2.0 profile for enough completeness percentage.

When I looked at the notification in the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ menu I saw <strike>a deer</strike> this:

[image: MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ image]

**Question is:** what is the freehand-circled number? Is that the grand total of all the invitations that has been issued or given to people for sharing? Or does this is not supposed to happen?

*Side question:* Is there live-statistics on Careers 2.0 that show the development of the site?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about that M'vy.  That number is actually your careers profile Id.  It's supposed to be the number of invitations you were granted (5 in this case).  The fix should be pushed shortly.